# Using a While for loop for a simulated coin flip in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop, simulation

I want to toss a coin and want it to stop when I get two consecutive heads in a row.

**Here is my code**

```
coin<-0:1
sample(coin, size = 1, replace = TRUE)

flip<-function(){
  coin<-0:1
  toss<-sample(coin, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
}
flip()

heads=1
tosses<-c()
while (heads=="?") {
  tosses=c(tosses, flip())
}
```

**I have my flip function made. I am not sure if I need use a if else statement or count the flips to check for back to back 1's after each coin flip? I am using a while for loop**

Comment: sidenote: no need to replace if size=1 ;-)

Comment: `if(sum(tail(tosses, 2)) == 2) break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to sindri's answer, but removing the need to check `length` at each iteration

```
while(sum(tail(tosses, 2)) != 2){
  tosses <- c(tosses, flip())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With minimum modification of your current code:

```
flip<-function(){
  coin<-0:1
  sample(coin, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
}

tosses<-c()
while (length(tosses) < 2 | !all(tail(tosses, 2) == 1)) {
  tosses=c(tosses, flip())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try `repeat`

```
repeat {
  tosses <- c(tosses, flip())
  if (mean(tail(tosses, 2)) == 1 & length(tosses) > 1) break
}
```